# How to open files from office excel task pane add-in?

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-addins, office-js

I'm developing an Office Excel Task Pane add-in, and I have the need to import the content of external files (other spreadsheets and PDF files) into the active workbook.

On VBA (also VB and C#), workbooks could be open with the Workbooks.Open() method, but it is not available on Office/Excel JS library.

So, how may I open files from Office/Excel Task Pane add-ins?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point in time our APIs do not support opening external applications.
Please feel free to submit your feature request at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/ and we will take it into account for future APIs.

Regards,
Philip, Developer on the Microsoft Office Extensibility team

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still, I'm not sure if we're talking exactly about the same thing. My question is regarding opening **files** from office.js, not an **external application**. I mean, being able to read file contents from user HD on client side (without opening any external application).

Comment: @GCSDC At this point in time we don't have APIs that allow opening other files from disk, but we may add it in the future. As I mentioned above, you can log your feature request and we will add it to our list for consideration.